# append pandas series in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have tries using pandas.Series().append() inside a loop but the return is the same Series that went into this method. I need this method to return a pandas Series with repeating values. The number of repetitions decided by num.

```
def expand(ser, num):
sers = ser
x = 0
while(x < num):
    sers.append(sers).reset_index(drop=True)
    x+=1
return sers
```

Comment: everything is indented correctly:

Comment: Please see the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); it may apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use [`pandas.Series.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

num = 3

repeated_s = s.repeat(num)
repeated_s

a    1.445775
a    1.445775
a    1.445775
b   -1.672416
b   -1.672416
b   -1.672416
c    1.551762
c    1.551762
c    1.551762
dtype: float64
```